# p:keyboard ajax events

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am using PrimeFaces. And on this Keyboard, would like to use an ajax event that fires every after a key is clicked.

Here is the code:

```
<p:keyboard placeholder="Search" value="#{menu.searchValue}" layout="qwertyBasic">
   <p:ajax event="click" listener="#{menu.search()}" update=":form:menuItems"/>
</p:keyboard>
```

This only works when I click in the field it's self, not when i click the keys on the keyboard.

I'm on JSF 2.2

Comment: No idea, did you check the javascript source of the component? It **is** open...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish that with p:keyboard attributes:

- onkeyup
- onkeypress
- onkeydown

For example:

```
<p:remoteCommand name="RC_name" 
                 actionListener="#{TestBean.function}" />

<p:keyboard placeholder="Search" 
            value="#{menu.searchValue}" 
            layout="qwertyBasic" 
            onkeyup="RC_name()" >
     <p:ajax event="click" 
             listener="#{menu.search()}" 
             update=":form:menuItems"/>
</p:keyboard>
```

Or if you want to catch specific key (for example ENTER click):

```
<p:keyboard value="#{menu.searchValue}" 
            onkeyup="if(event.keyCode == 13){
                          RC_name();
                          return false;
                     }" >
</p:keyboard>
```

Comment: You're welcome :) can you just mark the answer as solved the problem.